# syntax error jquery single quote

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags

i have jquery code like this, but when i click image **share**, its not working.
am i wrong about typing single quote ?

**onClick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('+my_var+')"**

```
var my_var="";
my_var="Hello World";

$('#info_detail').append('<table border="0"><tr><td><img src="favourite.png" onClick="
      set_favorit('+employee.info_id+')"></td><td><img src="share.png" onClick="
      window.plugins.socialsharing.share('+my_var+')"></td></tr></table>');
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because `my_var` is a string, therefore you need to wrap it in escaped quotes in the output. The same may be true for the `employee.info_id` value too:

```
$('#info_detail').append('<table border="0"><tr><td><img src="favourite.png" onClick="
  set_favorit(\'' + employee.info_id + '\')"></td><td><img src="share.png" onClick="
  window.plugins.socialsharing.share(\'' + my_var + '\')"></td></tr></table>');
```

You should however note that `on*` event attributes are very outdated and should be removed in favour of unobtrusive event handlers instead, like this:

```
$('#info_detail').append('<table border="0"><tr><td><img src="favourite.png" data-info-id="' + employee.info_id + '" class="favorit" /></td><td><img src="share.png" data-share="' + my_var + '" class="share"></td></tr></table>'); 

$('#info_detail').on('click', '.favorit', function() {
  set_favorit($(this).data('info-id'));
}).on('click', '.share', function() {
  window.plugins.socialsharing.share($(this).data('share'));
});
```

Comment: `("' + my_var + '")` still interferes with the quotes from the onClick attribute. 
 It should be `(\'' + my_var + '\')`.

Comment: @SvenTheSurfer that was a bit noob wasn't it! Thanks for telling me.

Comment: thank you both of you Rory and Sven..(\'' + my_var + '\') its working now

Answer (score 0):

Your onClick for the share image is rendering incorrectly.

```
onClick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('+my_var+')"
```

with `my_var = "Hello World"` becomes

```
onClick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share(Hello World)"
```

This is not only invalid because of the space, but also because it isn't being passed into as a string as you may be assuming. This can be remedied by adding single quotes to `my_var = "'Hello World'"`. You may also be better off adding click handlers outside the HTML itself.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var my_var="Hello World",
    employee = 'demo';

$('#info_detail').append('<table border="0"><tr><td><img src="favourite.png" data-info-id="' + set_favorit(employee) + '" class="favorit" /></td><td><img src="share.png" data-share="' + myVar(my_var) + '" class="share"></td></tr></table>'); 

function set_favorit(a) {
console.log(a)
}

function myVar(b) {
console.log(b)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="info_detail"></div>
```

As I don't have that window function, I have added some custom functions. Kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing both single quotes from the statement I tried running the code removing the quotes it worked on my end.

Here is the code.

```
var my_var="";
```

my_var="Hello World";

var employee = {
  info_id: 10
}

```
$('#info_detail').append('<table border="1"><tr><td><img src="favourite.png" onClick="set_favorit('+employee.info_id+')"></td><td><img src="share.png" onClick="alert(my_var)"></td></tr></table>');
```

Comment: This will cause my_var to be evaluated when clicked, which is probably not what OP intended.

Comment: Possibly, but if you are appending those rows and want, for example, each to have a unique output when clicked, using just the variable will not work.  They will all have the same output.